# Integrated Security = False

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I use in a `connection string`:

```
integrated security=false;username=aduffy;password=blah
```

I assume this equates to

> 1. I'm not using windows authentication
> 2. and these are my SQL Server authentication details? (aduffy & blah)

That about right?

Comment: should be... integrated security=false;user id=aduffy;password=blah

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from msdn

[Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Integrated Security When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.
>   If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.

Answer (score 1):

[`SqlConnection.ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) documents all of the valid SQL Server connection string keywords and their meanings.

**Integrated Security**:

> When **false**, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When **true**, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are **true**, **false**, **yes**, **no**, and **sspi** (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to **true**.
>   If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to **true**, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.
>   [`SqlCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential.aspx) is a more secure way to specify credentials for a connection that uses SQL Server Authentication (Integrated Security=**false**).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, to use the windows authentication you need to set `Integrated security = true`. Microsoft recommends SSPI when using windows authentication.

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When
>   true, the current Windows account credentials are used for
>   authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi
>   (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true. If User ID and
>   Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the
>   User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be
>   used. SqlCredential is a more secure way to specify credentials for a
>   connection that uses SQL Server Authentication (Integrated
>   Security=false).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If `Integrated Security=True` then it means the program will be using the current user's login to connect to SQL Server.
And If 
`Integrated Security=False` then it means the program/ software needs `User ID=*****;Password=*****;` in order to connect to SQL Server from the application.