# ASP.NET Intranet Config - Get Network User ID But Access Db And Folders As Different User

Tags: asp.net, authentication, intranet

I have looked at numerous articles and tried a multitude of settings, but I can't seem to achieve what I'm looking for in my intranet site.  Even if I don't get a solution, a definitive "you can't do that" will help me move forward.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Web site recognizes the user's network login credentials - ONLY so I can get their user ID without a login
2. The website uses some generic account (IUSR or something like that) to access a SQL Server that the same network users can NOT access EXCEPT through the website
3. Users can upload files to a set of folders created on-the-fly by the website to contain their files for later reference by them
4. The website can construct web pages on-the-fly with links to the users' files - and ONLY theirs - so they can open / download them through the web pages
5. Users can NOT access the uploaded files through a network share on the web server
6. All of the folder creation, file upload, and file serving occur under some generic account like IUSR

I currently have things configured to use Windows Authentication and I could probably live with that except I don't want to require a login to the site.  Apparently, in order to make this happen, I need to have the server configured as a trusted delegate and IT is dragging their feet on doing that.  Also, this config allows the users to access the SQL Server and folders/files through means other than the web site and I don't really want that.  I only need to pick off their user ID so I can use it to get information about them out of Active Directory and keep track of their interactions with the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer is not all that complex and it is a real mystery why it is so difficult to find a single source on the web to spell it out.  Here is my IIS authentication for an intranet app that acts exactly how I want:

- Enable ASP.NET Impersonation and edit to Authenticated User
- Enable Windows Authentication

  - Advanced Settings->Extended Protection->Off
  - Advanced Settings->Enable Kernel-mode authentication->unchecked
  - Providers->Available Providers->Negotiate:Kerberos and move that to the top
- Disable all other authentications
- Most critical: Make the server a 'trusted delegate' in Active Directory

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing your post I must first say "Yes" it seems like what you want to accomplish can be done. However the enormity of your question precludes simple posting answers. From what I gather there are three security issues you want to navigate 1) Windows Authentication, 2) Admin only SQL access, 3) User only Access to files and directories while authenticated using Active Directory.

I have been building ASP.net intranet web applications using Active Directory (Windows logins) for a few months. I would encourage you to explore this article: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages for details on setting up windows authentication in an ASP.net web application. You can add elements to your web pages using a section of Visual Studio [Toolbox] called 'Login', which contains elements such as 'LoginName'.

Next I am pretty sure you can control the SQL server query access using authentication parameters of your choosing. In the portion of the connectionString that is normally 'Integrated Security=True;' you will need to switch that to 'Integrated Security=False;username=sqlAdminUserName;password=sqlAdminPassword'. For more information I suggest reviewing this post: [Integrated Security = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403235/integrated-security-false).

For the third security issue once you have isolated the user's windows login identity you should be able to dynamically build web pages, files, directories, and whatever other resources you require all customized for that individual user. I believe the generation of all those materials can be done with an IUSR account with the only needed ingredient being the Windows login user identity.

Good Luck and I hope my suggestions help move you ahead.