# C# Run SQL Query on another machine

Tags: c#, sql, network-programming

Recently we have had an issue with our ERP retrieving some information from our database tables. While this is being fixed I have come up with some work arounds to temporarily, however, they only work because my user has access to the SQL database and can run queries on the database. I would like to distribute an executable program throughout the company (we are relatively small, so I am not worried about bottle-necking my computer) that would allow a different user on another computer to run a query through my computer and retrieve the information to then be output on their computer. This way we don't need to make any changes to users SQL permissions.

How could I possibly do this?

**Edit - Additional Info**

- User A - has permission to query the database on our servers from
  their workstation
- User B - does not have permission to query the db

User B needs to gather information from a specific db query, yet they don't have access to the db. All that User B needs, is to be returned a string with information from that query.

So not necessarily looking for the remote execution of a program per se, because then how would they get that return value?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?  Execute a program residing on one computer from another computer?  Remote execution?  This isn't really about SQL if that's the case...what the program does is irrelevant.

Comment: Is it not possible to just setup an SQL Server user account that your program could use to execute the SQL?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want. Please explain a little more what you need.

Comment: @rory.ap added some more info to the question Let me know if that clarifies.

Comment: You can create a _view_ or _function_ that only returns the data that User B needs and then give User B permissions on that view only.  That way, User B would not have general access to the db and can still get the data she needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with an application that does something like this.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WinformFiddle
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=myserver.mydomain.edu;user id=MyUserWithAccessUsername;password=MyUserWithAccessPassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=roomscheduling;Integrated Security=False";
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand selCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ...", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selCmd);
            ....
```

This uses MySql, but the exact equivalent can be done with any DB provider.  The part of the connection string that says `Integrated Security=False` tells the system [not to use the current user's window credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403364/4843530) but rather what is being provided in the connection string.

The same thing but using Sql Server, I think, would be like this (it's been a while since I use sql server...

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WinformFiddle
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=myserver.mydomain.edu;user id=MyUserWithAccessUsername;password=MyUserWithAccessPassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=roomscheduling;Integrated Security=False";
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selCmd);
            ....
```

Comment: So... for the most part this is working, however, I can't seem to login properly to the database. I use my windows login that I typically use. Also used the administrator etc... what would the user id need to be?

Comment: You can find more info about how to construct that connection string at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx you may have to play with the server, and you may have to provide an initial catalog.  Something like "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Server=MySqlServer\MSSQL1;"

Answer (score 0):

I assume based on the quote below - you are creating a program that you will send to user B to use to run the query and return a string.
 "that would allow a different user on another computer to run a query through my computer and retrieve the information to then be output on their computer. "

If this is the case - User B doesnt need any data base permissions. You will put your [user A]'s username and password in the connection string of the program you create. So when User B runs this program you gave him, it will use User As permissions to run and return data.

like this:

```
 <add name="myconnection" connectionString="data source=yoursqlserver;initial catalog=yourdataabase;persist security info=True;user id=UserA;password=userAspassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I'd be surprised that they would be OK with user B knowing User A password.

Comment: This is the right answer, and user b does not need to know User A's password.  You can put that in the application code where the app's user will never see it.

Comment: I'm not necessarily sure this would be possible since we use windows auth

Comment: It is possible.  When you create a database connection in the application, you specify the connection parameters, and you can say not to use the user's windows credentials, but rather use specific credentials for connecting to the db.

Comment: Put your windows username and password in connection string.

Comment: And do not put that into a connection string that will go in a config file.  That would end up in a human readable file deployed with the app.  Put it in the code.

Comment: @AgapwIesu right - I would most likely be putting that into Settings (using VS), which I believe hides that.